# Generating $m$ subsets each with size $l$ from a $N$ character alphabet with maximal overlap of $k$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given an alphabet with size $N$, one can generate $\binom{N}{l}$ different subsets of size $l$. A subset of that subsets can be chosen such that no two members have an intersection with more than $k$ elements. The largest such subset has $m=m(N,l,k)$ members.

For example, for $N=10, l=5, k=2$, $m$ should be 6 (if I'm not mistaken):

```
ABCDE
ABFGH
ACFIJ
BDGIJ
CEGHI
DEFHJ
```

Question: for given $N, l, k$, what is $m$? Conversely, for given $l, k, m$, what is the smallest $N$?